# How to count a pair of texts in one column that are few rows apart using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

In workbook A, I'm trying to count when a text, "Dr" occurs then within 5 rows after it, how many cells are blank or the cell is either a text, "Nr" or "Cr".
In another word, I'm trying to count the numbers of pairs of "DR-blank(within 5 rows after DR)", "DR-NF(within 5 rows after DR)", and "DR-CR(within 5 rows after DR)". The data set looks like this:

Column A  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
Column B     Dr    Cr    Dr       Nr

And then I want to copy the result to workbook B.

I've been tried to use offset:

```
If Range("B2:B901").Value = "D" Then
      'V3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Range("B2:B901").Offset(5, 0))

       Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = V3
```

But I always got a "0" in return, meaning the logic wasn't quite right to capture what I intended to do.
Could someone help with the codes? Really appreciated!

Comment: You can't compare a range of cells with a single value, you have to loop through (depending on exactly what you are trying to do as I'm not sure). A screenshot would help more, your example isn't clear.

Comment: I'm new to the site. Not sure how to post a screen shot. Could you provide more directions?

Answer (score 0):

This code will iterate through every cell in the range you provide (in this case `B1:B901` in `sheet1`) and if it contains the vale `Dr` it will then iterate through the subsequent 5 cells to check if they contain the values you are looking for.

It will output the contents of `column A` and `column B` to a new workbook, together with your count of `nr`, `cr` and `blank` in columns `c`, `d` and `e` respectively.

```
    Option Compare Text 'this tells VBA that you want you string comparisons to NOT be
                        'case sesitive. If you want case to be taken into account, then leave 
                        'this line out.

Sub test()

Dim cll As Range
Dim vCellValue As Variant
Dim iterator As Integer
Dim vCountBlank As Integer
Dim vCountCr As Integer
Dim vCountNr As Integer
Dim wb2 As Workbook




Set wb2 = Workbooks.Add

    For Each cll In Sheet1.Range("B2:B901")

        vCountBlank = 0
        vCountCr = 0
        vCountNr = 0


        If cll.Value = "Dr" Then

            For iterator = 1 To 5

                vCellValue = cll.Offset(iterator, 0).Value
                If vCellValue = "Nr" Then vCountNr = vCountNr + 1
                If vCellValue = "Cr" Then vCountCr = vCountCr + 1
                If vCellValue = "" Then vCountBlank = vCountBlank + 1

            Next iterator

        End If

        wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(cll.Row, 1).Value = cll.Offset(0, -1).Value
        wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(cll.Row, 2).Value = cll.Value
        wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(cll.Row, 3).Value = vCountNr
        wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(cll.Row, 4).Value = vCountCr
        wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(cll.Row, 5).Value = vCountBlank


    Next cll


Set wb2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response! I didn't run into any error message but it didn't show the vCount, neither.

Comment: Hi again, I opened up the immediate window and was able to see the print but it the vCount always showed the result of the number of iteration*number of "Dr", not the number of pairs of "Dr-blank", "Dr-Nr", or "Dr-Cr". That is, if "Dr" occurred and then within 5 rows followed by a blank cell, a "Nr", or a "Cr". I would like to count from the cell with "Dr" to 5 rows below as one instance and sum up all three conditions. Hope this makes my question clearer.

Comment: @Student I think I understand what you are looking for now. I have edited the code accordingly, and I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi DMcLaren, thanks so much for your codes! It worked but not exactly what I meant. The codes: wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(cll.Row, 3).Value = vCountNr
        wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(cll.Row, 4).Value = vCountCr
        wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(cll.Row, 5).Value = vCountBlank